# How to fix <"faultstring":"The Service is temporarily unavailable"> error while setting up API proxy using apigee?

Tags: continuous-integration, artifactory, release-management, apigee

I am trying to setup an API proxy with apigee with a trail account.

I am facing issue in accessing the target endpoint (URL is correctly accessible directly via the browser).

XML part of the API proxy is as below:

```
<TargetEndpoint name="default">
    <Description/>
    <FaultRules/>
    <PreFlow name="PreFlow">
        <Request/>
        <Response/>
    </PreFlow>
    <PostFlow name="PostFlow">
        <Request/>
        <Response/>
    </PostFlow>
    <Flows/>
    <HTTPTargetConnection>
        <Properties/>
        <URL>http://xyz. com/artifactory/app/</URL>
    </HTTPTargetConnection>
</TargetEndpoint>
```

Expected:

`Error code 200` and page should load.

Actual:

```
{
     "fault":{
          "faultstring":"The Service is temporarily unavailable",
          "detail":{
              "errorcode":"messaging.adaptors.http.flow.ServiceUnavailable"
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: although you say the url is accessible via browser, it looks a bit strange. the Artifactory base URL usually looks like http://<yourserver>/artifactory or http://<server>:<port>/artifactory

Comment: You are right. The URL is **http://example.com/artifactory**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that, the artifactory base URL does not have access from a trial account. After creating another proxy with 'official' account (which had access), the links are working fine and the files are getting downloaded.

In short, the apigee account needs access to the artifactory.

Comment: How to create an official account? Please guide me because I am having this problem